# MSSQL Server Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using sql server and am trying to see how I can set a variable to a list of locations like such:

```
Declare @StartDate datetime,
        @EndDate datetime,
        @EmpName varchar(50),
        @LOCID varchar(25);

Set @StartDate = '2016/01/01';
Set @EndDate = '2019/02/01';
Set @EmpName = 'David Brierton';
Set @LOCID =  ('desoto_tickets','ccc_tickets');

select 
  ID,
  requester_name,
  requester_id,
  COUNT(*) as numberOfTickets
from Tickets
where created_at between @StartDate and @EndDate
  and requester_name = @EmpName
  and ',' + tags + ',' like '%,' + @LOCID + ',%'
group by Id, requester_name, requester_id
```

I am getting an error for the comma in `Set @LOCID =  ('desoto_tickets','ccc_tickets');`

Error states:

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

What am I doing wrong here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
In the database in the tags column each tag is listed like this:
`desoto_counter,desoto_tickets,new_associate_workchecked,new_hire__paperwork_check__transaction_complete___express,newhire_assistance,no_error,ops,walk`

Each row has a list of tags like this in the database.

New Edit:

```
    Declare @StartDate datetime,
        @EndDate datetime,
    --  @EmpName varchar(50),
        @LOCID1 varchar(25),
        @LOCID2 varchar(25),
        @LOCID3 varchar(25),
        @LOCID4 varchar(25),
        @LOCID5 varchar(25),
        @LOCID6 varchar(25);

Set @StartDate = '2016/01/01';
Set @EndDate = '2019/02/01';
-- Set @EmpName = 'David Brierton';
Set @LOCID1 =  'desoto_counter';
Set @LOCID2 =  'lwr_counter';
Set @LOCID3 =  'nr_tickets';
Set @LOCID4 =  'ps_tickets';
Set @LOCID5 =  'sdl_tickets';
Set @LOCID5 =  'ccc_tickets';

select 
  ID,
  requester_name,
  requester_id,
  COUNT(*) as numberOfTickets,
  case
when tags like '%,' + @LOCID1 + ',%' then 'CDS'
     tags like '%,' + @LOCID2 + ',%' then 'CLR'
     tags like '%,' + @LOCID3 + ',%' then 'CNR'
     tags like '%,' + @LOCID4 + ',%' then 'CPS'
     tags like '%,' + @LOCID5 + ',%' then 'SDL'
     tags like '%,' + @LOCID6 + ',%' then 'CCC'
else 'Unknown'
end [Location],
from Tickets
where created_at between @StartDate and @EndDate
 -- and requester_name = @EmpName
  and ',' + tags + ',' like '%,' + @LOCID1 + ',%'
  or ',' + tags + ',' like '%,' + @LOCID2 + ',%'
  or ',' + tags + ',' like '%,' + @LOCID3 + ',%'
  or ',' + tags + ',' like '%,' + @LOCID4 + ',%'
  or ',' + tags + ',' like '%,' + @LOCID5 + ',%'
  or ',' + tags + ',' like '%,' + @LOCID6 + ',%'
group by Id, requester_name, requester_id
```

Comment: Here `Set @LOCID =  ('desoto_tickets','ccc_tickets');` is problem. Maybe `Set @LOCID =  CONCAT('desoto_tickets',',','ccc_tickets');;`

Comment: What result are you trying to get?  What do you want `@LOCID` to contain?   An array?   There are no arrays in TSQL.

Comment: Do you mean `SET @LOCID =  'desoto_tickets,ccc_tickets';`? I would advise against syntax like `',' + tags + ',' like '%,' + @LOCID + ',%'` though. Use a string splitter or a table variable.

Comment: If you want the variable to contain a comma-separated string, then Larnu's comment is the way to do it.

Comment: You can't assign multiple values to a scalar variable.

Comment: `('desoto_tickets','ccc_tickets')` is not a valid VARCHAR value. Looks like you try to store two strings into a single VARCHAR variable, that simply is not possible.

Comment: @DavidBrierton it would search the entire string as a single comma-separated string.

Comment: XY question.  Give an example data in the table and what results you want to get from your query.   It's not clear to me what you're trying to do.

Comment: An example would be a LOT clearer than any of the explanations in the comments above this one.

Comment: @DavidBrierton Ok, now the question is clear, and Larnu's answer is the way to go.

Comment: @DavidBrierton yes, if you use a UNION query instead of a bunch of `OR` clauses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going to expand on my comment. Firstly, the syntax you are using is:

```
SET @LOCID =  ('desoto_tickets','ccc_tickets');
```

This isn't valid value as a scalar variable can only contain 1 value. If you want to store a delimited string, then it needs to be 1 (literal) value:

```
SET @LOCID =  'desoto_tickets,ccc_tickets';
```

However, the `WHERE` clause you have isn't ideal, specifically:

```
AND ',' + tags + ',' LIKE '%,' + @LOCID + ',%'
```

Instead of using syntax like that, I suggest using a splitter. if you're on SQL Server 2016+, you can use `STRING_SPLIT:`

```
SELECT ID,
       requester_name,
       requester_id,
       COUNT(*) AS numberOfTickets
FROM Tickets T
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(@LOCID,',') SS
WHERE created_at BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
  AND requester_name = @EmpName
  AND SS.[value] = T.Tags --Assumes tags isn't delimited either, if it is, then your data is flawed
GROUP BY Id,
         requester_name,
         requester_id;
```

If you're on SQL Server 2008, search `delimitedsplit8k`, and if you're on 2012/2014 then `delimitedsplit8k_lead`.

Alternatively, you can use a table variable:

```
DECLARE @Loc table (tag varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @Loc
VALUES('desoto_tickets'),('ccc_tickets');

SELECT ID,
       requester_name,
       requester_id,
       COUNT(*) AS numberOfTickets
FROM Tickets T
     JOIN @Loc L ON T.tags = L.Tag --Assumes tags isn't delimited either, if it is, then your data is flawed
WHERE created_at BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
  AND requester_name = @EmpName
GROUP BY Id,
         requester_name,
         requester_id;
```

*Edit: Ok, the OP's data is flawed. I will update this answer to fix their data shortly.*

*Edit 2: The below "fixes" the OP's data. Please note the Cleanup near the end **AND** the `DROP`. To the OP, make sure you fix **ALL** your references before you `DROP` the column `tags`*:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO
--Create a sample table
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tickets (ID int IDENTITY,
                          RequesterID int,
                          Tags varchar(MAX));
INSERT INTO dbo.Tickets (RequesterID,
                         Tags)
VALUES (1,'desoto_counter,desoto_tickets,new_associate_workchecked,new_hire__paperwork_check__transaction_complete___express,newhire_assistance,no_error,ops,walk'),
       (2,'newhire_assistance,new_associate_workchecked,no_error');
GO
--Create 2 additional tables
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tags (ID int IDENTITY,
                       TagName varchar(100))

CREATE TABLE dbo.TicketTags (TicketTagID int IDENTITY,
                             TicketID int, --Should be a FOREIGN KEY
                             TagID int); --Should be a FOREIGN KEY

GO
--Get the unique tags. This might be slow if you have a lot of tickets

INSERT INTO dbo.Tags (TagName)
SELECT DISTINCT [value]
FROM tickets t
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Tags,',') SS; --Assumes 2016+ see prior part of answer if not
GO
--Now populate the relational table

INSERT INTO dbo.TicketTags (TicketID,
                            TagID)
SELECT T.ID,
       tags.ID
FROM dbo.tickets T
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Tags,',') SS --Assumes 2016+ see prior part of answer if not
     JOIN dbo.Tags ON SS.[value] = tags.TagName;

GO

--Then drop tbhe old column, which you might want to do LATER
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tickets DROP COLUMN tags;
GO

--And now your "new" query.

DECLARE @Loc table (tag varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @Loc
VALUES('desoto_tickets'),('ccc_tickets');

SELECT *
FROM tickets t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.TicketTags TT
                   JOIN dbo.Tags ON TT.TagID = dbo.Tags.ID
                   JOIN @Loc L ON tags.TagName = L.tag
               WHERE TT.TicketID = T.ID);
GO

--Clean up
DROP TABLE dbo.TicketTags;
DROP TABLE dbo.Tags;
DROP TABLE dbo.Tickets
```

Comment: @DavidBrierton that new edit is still suffering from the flaw of your column `tags` having multiple values. You need to fix that.

Comment: What you have now isn't going to scale @DavidBrierton . The short answer is "No". The long answer is, again, my answer. it explains what what's wrong, and how to fix it. Don't store multiple values in a single row/column. If you are using delimited data, change your design and normalise it; as I show above.

Comment: Then you'll need to split both your column and then compare it to the variable (either by splitting it as a delimited `varchar` orr using a `table` variable); you can use my answer here to see how you manage that as it does cover it.

Comment: This implies you don't understand my answer then @DavidBrierton . It's important you do; which bits don't you understand?